# How to get users by specific ID's WordPress

Tags: wordpress

How to get users by specific users ID's in WordPress.

```
$args = array(
        'number'    => -1,
        'fields'    => array( 'ID', 'user_email', 'display_name', 'user_url' )
    );

$users = get_users( $args);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the correct answer.

```php
$args = [
  'include' => [ 1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,12,20 ], // ID's of users you want to get
  'fields'  => [ 'ID', 'user_email', 'display_name', 'user_url' ],
];

$users = get_users( $args );
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming user id is 1

```
$u_id = 1;
```

You can use this function

```
$u_data = get_user_by( 'id', $u_id );
echo "<pre>"; print_r( $u_data); // Check whole array
```

OR You can use this function

```
$user_info = get_userdata( $u_id );
echo "<pre>"; print_r( $user_info ); // Check whole array
```

Or you can use query

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'users';

$arr_user = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . $table_name  . " WHERE ID= '" . $u_id . "'");
echo "<pre>"; print_r( $arr_user ); // Check whole array
```

Comment: Thanks, But I want maultiple users ID's. this is just for one ID.

Comment: you can use query like this `WHERE ID IN (value1, value2, ...);`

Comment: Thanks. just got an answer.
$args [
  'include' => [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], // Get users of these IDs.
  'fields'   => [ 'ID', 'user_email', 'display_name', 'user_url' ],
];
$users = get_users( $args );

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Amir!

That's my case:

```
    $userIDs = array(1,2,3) // Array of user id's 
    $users = get_users(
       array(
       'include' => $userIDs, // These are the ID's of users 
       )
    );
```